# Case study of virtual memory management

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

Need to understand virtual memory concept.

When a process requesting for 2GB mapping onto the virutal memory in Linux environment of 4GB ( 1GB Kernel : 3GB Userspace), when already another process already holds the mapping for 2 GB.

How does the mapping of the stack, heap, data segments all going to happen?
I am not able to find any example for my understanding.
Text book only mentions separately for each mapping but not a practical approach.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. In a 32-bit environment (address space 4GiB total), if a process already holds a mapping of size 2GB and it requests another mapping of size 2GB, then the second mapping will simply fail. There isn't enough space. That's all there is to it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion,
its not the same process requesting another mapping.
Its one process requesting mapping while another already holds the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that we have 3 GiB of virtual address space available and that a process' text, stack, heap, and prior memory mappings together occupy only a small amount of address space (much less than 1 GiB). Then if this process requests a mapping of size 2GB then there is no problem, there is plenty of space to accommodate that mapping.

(Actually, there would be one small case where this is not true: if the process' existing mappings were fragmented and scattered around the address space and there was no *contiguous* 2GB range of addresses available. But that's unlikely).

What mappings are or are not present in a different process' address space has nothing to do with it.